# How do i read netcdf files in c++ from a visual studio project?

Tags: c++, netcdf

I'm working within a c++ visual studio 2019 project and am trying to read data from a netcdf file. I've download the netcdf-c library from unidata but I've been unable to get it to work. how do I use it to read netcdf data using c++ in visual studio 2019?

Answer (score 0):

I recently saw a post that creates a custom `readnc` class in C++. I haven't used it personally (yet), but maybe it might help. (https://gerasimosmichalitsianos.wordpress.com/2017/12/13/usingcppwithnetcdf/)